# Add new option to select list without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown select list which is populated from a MySQL table.

```
<select name="displayfloor" class="datatext" id="displayfloor">
<option></option>
<option value="new">Add new floor</option> // ADD NEW OPTION
<?php do { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_SignageFloors['FloorName']?>"><?php echo $row_SignageFloors['FloorName'];?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_SignageFloors = mysql_fetch_assoc($SignageFloors));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($SignageFloors);
if($rows > 0) {
mysql_data_seek($SignageFloors, 0);
$row_SignageFloors = mysql_fetch_assoc($SignageFloors);
}
?>
</select>
```

In the list is an option to create a new floor and when it is selected it open a modal form where the new floor number can be entered. When this form is submitted it writes the new ada to the MySQL table using a Ajax script, see below.. This works fine.

```
$('#floor_insert').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $('form')[3];
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  $.ajax({
    url: "insert_new_floor_ajax.php",
    data: formData,
    method:"POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#add_floor_modal').modal("hide")    //alert(data);
    }
  })
 });
```

Is there a way I can refresh the select list without refreshing the page? I have looked at a number of question here and else where but none seem to deal with this situation.

Comment: you can refresh the DOM using DOM manipulation

Comment: `$("#displayfloor").append("<option>new option</option>");`  what am I missing in this question?

Comment: @ freedomn-m hi and thanks for your reply. If I use your code it inserts "new option" and not the data inserted to the data table, i.e what the user typed. Any ideas?

Comment: In formData, what is the ID of the input box used for the name?

Comment: id="displayfloor"

Comment: @DCJones that's the ID of the `select` not in `input` in the modal

Comment: Well, obviously, but it's how to insert an option that you asked, explicitly "*Add new option to select list*".  You haven't included an input for "what the user typed", so it would be just a guess:  `$("#displayfloor").append("<option>" + $("#floorInput").val() + "</option>");`

Comment: @freedomn-m Hi I made an adjustment to your code and now it works.  success: function(data) {$("#displayfloor").append("<option>" + data + "</option>");
            $('#add_floor_modal').modal("hide"); }. by using the data returned by the insert script. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @freedomn-m is there a way to force the new option to be auto selected?

Comment: Updated answer to include this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Add new option to select list without refreshing the page

To add a new `option` with jquery, you use:

```
$("#selectId").append("<option>" + textofoption + "</option>");
```

if you want to get the new text from an input:

```
var textofoption = $("#input").val()
```

to make the new option selected, add `selected` as it is created - this could also be achieved after the options has been added by changing the `.val()` of the select or setting `checked` on the option, but easiest to add as it's created:

```
$("#selectId").append("<option selected>" + textofoption + "</option>");
```

Example:

```js
$("#b").click(function() {
  var opt = $("#newopt").val();
  $("#s").append("<option selected>" + opt + "</option>");
  $("#newopt").val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='s'>
  <option>Option 1</option>
</select>
<hr/> Enter new option: <input type='text' id='newopt' /><button id='b' type='button'>click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the AJAX request is successful then you can just append the option to the `select` like this in the success part:

```
$("#displayfloor").append("<option value=" + $("#idofinput").val() + " selected>" + $("#idofinput").val() + "</option>");
```

Where `idofinput` is the ID of the `input` box where the user types out the name of the new item. This will automatically select the newly appended option.